# Solution of linearly dependent functions

Tags: functions, independence

I'm having a lot of trouble with this question. I know they are not linearly independent, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Here is the problem:
[image: problem]
Thank you.

Comment: Well how do you know they are not independent? To discover that you must have found a linear combination that vanishes everywhere, so you have the coefficients to enter.

Comment: @EthanBolker I entered all 0 and it says it was wrong that's the only reason, I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Comment: You didn't read the instructions (all $0$ is what you enter when they are independent). Now you have an answer from @LukeCollins .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's straightforward to see that $$f-g+2h=0.$$

---

*Explanation:* If $X=e^{3x}$ and $Y=\cos 5x$, you want to find $a,b,c$ such that $$a(X-Y)+b(X+Y)+cY=(a+b)X+(-a+b+c)Y=0.$$ I found $1$, $-1$ and $2$ simply by guessing.

Comment: Thank you very much that helps!